# How to delete pages in a word document dynamically

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word

I need to delete a few pages in a word document dynamically, the page numbers will be fetched from a configuration file. How can i delete a particular page.

Comment: You can find your answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754154/interop-word-delete-page-from-document

Comment: @KosalaW - Even this link you shared also not C#. It is VB or VBA Macro (Indeed lines of code are same for Word/Office Programming)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the VBA Macro for what you need. You can easily translate it to C#

```
Selection.HomeKey wdStory
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Count:=3
Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Select
Selection.Delete
```

3 in the above code is the page number I want to delete. You can use a for-loop and start deleting pages in descending order (In case you use ascending order the page numbers do change and you will end up deleting something other than what are intended to be deleted).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question is related to C#; not VBA.

Comment: @KosalaW - I do understand. I don't have Visual Studio handy. So I typed it in a word macro. Same API would be used while writing code in C#. Just that instead of **Selection** it will be **objDoc.Application.Selection**. Intellisense would definitely help.

Comment: Hi Kosala, thanks for ur help....but it is not working for C#...its not accepting (/Page).....

Comment: Thers no option wdStory in C#.instead i get objWordDoc1.Application.Selection.HomeKey(Word.WdStoryType) and for the "\Page it says bookmark cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Please check the below code in c#. objWordDoc1.Application.Selection.HomeKey(Word.WdStoryType); objWordDoc1.Application.Selection.GoTo(WordObj.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WordObj.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute, 1); objWordDoc1.Application.Selection.Bookmarks("\Page") objWordDoc1.Application.Selection.Delete();

Comment: Can you try with this? _objApp.Selection.Bookmarks[@"\Page"].Select();_

Comment: Hi Prash,thanks for the help.It worked fine,But thers a small hitch.when im trying to delete multiple pages randomly using a loop,then for every iteration it increase the page number to be deleted also... ex:-say if im inserting 3,6,9 pages from a word document.it deletes 3,7,11 pages.

Comment: Glad to hear!! Delete 9, 6, 3. Such way, numbers of the page always remains same.

Comment: Whoa it worked great Prash....but im not able to understand why it kept changing before(for 3,6,9) and how is it working now(for 9,6,3)...

Comment: Great!! Feel free to mark it as answer whenever the system allows you to do so!! - And yes, regarding the reverse order; once you delete 3rd page, then the actual 4th page becomes 3 now, likewise the 6th page that you wanted to deleted would be the 7th page before you started the operation (and it continues..). So if you remove the last page first, all the pages before that would continue to have the same page number and the pages/items that get deleted are what you wanted to have deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Its deleting pages 1,4,7.where i want to delete pages 1,3,5.
> ```

```
  int num = objWordDoc.ComputeStatistics(stat, ref missing);
                int[] a = { 1,3,5};
                for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
                {
                    object page_num = a[i];                    
                    objWordDoc.Application.Selection.GoTo(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute, num, page_num);
                    objWordDoc.Application.Selection.Bookmarks[@"\Page"].Select();                                        
                    objWordDoc.Application.Selection.Delete();         

                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Its deleting pages 1,4,7.where i want to delete pages 1,3,5.

this is simple: when you delete page 1 then your page 3 becomes page 2 and if you still deleting page 3 then you actually delete former page 4
and so on

just reverse array in your code and you'll be fine {5,3,1}